# Can't get Joomla Site Modules to enable

Tags: joomla, joomla-extensions

With Joomla 3.8.6, I'm trying to enable several site modules that were once enabled on the site before a recent redesign. The screen I'm looking at is the Extensions > Modules screen. First I search for the module name ("calculator") which produces a list of all the modules with that string in the Title. The Status column has the disabled icon (red circle with horizontal line). Clicking the icon does nothing. Hovering over it tells me I need to use Extensions ==> Manage to enable them.

So I go to Extensions ==> Manage ==> Manage and search for "calculator". Nothing comes up. Figuring they're not installed yet, I go to Install > Install from Folder, enter the path to the /public_html/modules folder where all the modules reside and click "Check and Install". It says "Installation of the module was successful.

I go back to Extensions ==> Manage ==> Manage and search for "calculator". Again, nothing comes up.

How do I enable these?

Comment: Is the exact name of this extension "calculator"? Or it is just a module name? You can name module whatever you want, but Extension has fixed name.

Comment: There are multiple modules that have different names, but all with "calculator" as part of the name. Here's a screenshot. https://s14.postimg.org/d46nwraap/Modules_Administration.png

Comment: Yes, that is OK, but my question is: Are they created from other extension or component? Who is the "manufacturer" :)

Comment: It's a custom module built by a developer we hired in the past who is no longer available. I did find out how to enable the modules. I'll update this with my own answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer in this case was that the module wasn't getting installed fully through the normal installation process. I had to use the "Discover" option as outlined in [this article](https://szoupi.com/blog/28-joomla-tutorials/921-how-to-install-extensions-in-joomla#discover).

1. Go to `Extensions > Manage > Discover`
2. Select `Discover` button
3. Tick the extensions to be installed
4. Click `Install` button